# How to reverse the OneHotEncoding to calculate the coef_ with sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

After computing a linear regression and calculate my R2 score, I would like to calculate the coefficients (with the sklearn coef_ attribute ) of my features.

The point is that in my features I have some numerical and some categorical data. To process the LinearRegression() I have OneHotEncoded my categorical values. So in this case it is not possible to directly calculate the coef_ of each feature.

How would you recover the process to have one single column for each categorial feature (because OneHotEncoding means as many columns as possible values ​​for each categorial feature).

I saw this great post : https://katstam.com/regression-feature_importance/ which could solve my problem. I added this line to my notebook (at the bottom of the article) :

```
onehot_columns = list(clf.named_steps['preprocessor'].named_transformers_['cat'].named_steps['one_hot'].get_feature_names(input_features=categorical_features))
```

and :

```
numeric_features_list = list(numeric_features)
numeric_features_list.extend(onehot_columns)
```

But I don't what "clf" refers to.

In the article, "clf" refers to this object :

```
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', LinearRegression())])
```

But in my notebook I handle the preprocessing and the linear regression in two separated steps so I don't have the equivalent of this "clf" objet.

Do you have any idea or maybe another method to use ?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the post you are referring to has these features at the beginning of the post: *house price, location, age, interest, interest rate, year* and all of a sudden when he/she is displaying the importance weights from ELI5, the features are: *relationship, marital_status, education_num, etc*. In other words, I don't thing that the author is displaying the weights of the dataset he/she is claiming to have used.

Having said that, what you want to do is not possible and for a reason. If you think about it, you have given your model (Linear Regression) a set of features. These features are the numerical ones but also the one-hot encoded ones. The model has learned the weights of those final features not the initial (*raw*) ones! So, even if you do retrieve the weights of all the features, you will have an array of float numbers (*the weights*) that correspond to the final feature vector you used to train your model.

Let me give you a picture:

Imagine you have *gender* as a categorical feature and you do One-Hot Encoding. At the end, you will have the features *gender_male*, *gender_female*, *gender_non-binary*, alongside *location, age, interest, ...*. This is the feature space the model is going to be exposed to. On this feature space, the model will learn its weights. And at the end you will have a weight for each of the categories of the categorical variable *gender*.